# Qt & Prepending one QMenu to another QMenu

Tags: c++, qt, qmenu

Using Qt5, say I have a control implementing its own context menu. And suppose that under some conditions I want to **prepend** some items to the standard context menu. So, to do this I create a temporary QMenu, add some stuff to it and the append the standard menu. Something like:

```
// MyControl is derived from QPlainTextEdit
void MyControl::showContextMenu(const QPoint& pos)
{
    // This is QPlainTextEdit::createStandardContextMenu()
    QMenu* contextMenu = createStandardContextMenu();

    if (someCondition)
    {
        QMenu* tempMenu = new QMenu(this);
        /* add several actions to tempMenu */

        tempMenu->addSeperator();

        for (auto a : contextMenu->actions)
        {
            tempMenu->addAction(a);
        }

        // Feel like I should delete the original QMenu here but doing this
        // will delete the QActions it created
        // delete contextMenu; 
        contextMenu = tempMenu;
    }

    contextMenu->exec(mapToGlobal(pos));
    delete contextMenu;
}
```

My question is, isn't this introducing a memory leak? And if so, what is the correct way to go about this? I can't `delete contextMenu` before I do `contextMenu = newMenu;` because that apparently deletes the actions I want.

EDIT:

Ultimately what I want to do is use `createStandardContextMenu()` which returns a allocated QMenu, and then add some QActions to the **top** of the menu, and make sure nothing leaks.

Comment: It seems like newMenu and tempMenu the same? But the code is then incorrect. Yes, tempMenu leaks there if not fixed. Now it looks like contextMenu is leaking as well. No idea why you do all that.

Comment: Yes, they were the same. Sorry about that, I've fixed it.

Comment: @Addy, to avoid memory leaking you can use [`QSharedPointer`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsharedpointer.html#operator-eq) instead of common pointer

Comment: @VladimirBershov I didn't even think of that but that's a great and simple idea. Thank you!

Comment: @VladimirBershov Your advice is not really applicable to widgets as long as they can have parent responsible for the object destruction. I would not use shared pointer with widgets.

Answer (score 1):

`QWidget::addAction(QAction*)` does not take ownership of the action. Whether deleting `contextMenu` will result in deletion of actions depends on how `createStandardContextMenu` is implemented (e. g. `QMenu::addAction(QString)` does take ownership of the action it creates).

So the actions that are owned by the original menu should be re-parented:

```
for (auto a : contextMenu->actions)
    {
        tempMenu->addAction(a);
        if (a->parent() == contextMenu){
            a->setParent(tempMenu);
        }
    }
delete contextMenu;
contextMenu = tempMenu;
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `insertAction` on the `QMenu` to insert custom actions before the first standard action, like this:

```
QMenu* contextMenu = createStandardContextMenu();
QAction* first = contextMenu->actions().at(0);
QAction* customAction = /* Create some custom action */
contextMenu->insertAction(first, customAction);
```

EDIT: You can then use `insertSeparator` to separate your custom actions from the first standard action.

Answer (score -1):

Context menu should be modal dialog, so dont use dynamic allocation, and pass "this" to contructor, and build menu depending on passed context

```
(condition)
{
     context.add(...);
}

CustomMenu menu(this,context);
menu.exec(mapToGlobal(point));
```

no rep to add comment, so

```
 QMenu* tempMenu = new QMenu(this);
```

no, this wont leak, since you pass pointer of parent object.

Comment: I don't believe this answer offers me a solution of how to conditionally prepend items to an already existing `QMenu` without leaks. Also, `createStandardContextMenu()` returns a dynamically allocated `QMenu`, do I have no choice but to use it.

Comment: pass context to createStandardContextMenu(), add constructor to CustomMenu which process data, else rename CustomMenu into DummyMenu, cuz it does nothing.

Comment: `createStandardContextMenu` is a Qt function that can only take a QPoint.

Comment: setContextMenuPolicy(Qt::CustomContextMenu); connect(this,SIGNAL(customContextMenuRequested(const QPoint &)), this, SLOT(onCustomContextMenu(const QPoint &))); create local variable which subclass from QMenu